# How to get the sms bar?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Does anyone know what this bar is called and how to obtain it?

[image]

Comment: I have no freakin' clue... but the Catholic altar boy in me was definitely curious about the "Kyrie Eleison" in the URL :-)  PS: This link might give you info about the default iPhone SMS msgs app in question: http://www.iphone-tips-and-advice.com/text-messages.html

Comment: Thanks. and yea, I'm catholic too and it was an easy name to come up with long time ago haha. But it's Kyrian, not Kyrie :P

Answer (score 4):

There's no "name" for it really, you will have to create a `UIToolbar` adding the 2 `UIButtons` and a `UITextField`.

Comment: Wow thanks! Haha I somehow knew I'd have to make it myself. Thanks again (: But do you happen to know how to make the Toolbar move up with the keyboard when i select the TextField?

Comment: you can look for keyboard notifications and animate the frame of the toolbar when the keyboard shows.

Comment: Provided that you don't need to support anything earlier than iOS 3.2, you could set the inputAccessoryView property of the textField to be the toolbar. It would then animate up and down automatically as the keyboard shows and hides.